# Xarray: How to Merge Multiple Coordinates Assigned to Different Variables into a Single Coordinate

Tags: python, python-xarray

I have this xarray dataset where each variable has their own coordinate `ensemble_X`, even though they all have the same values (same thing for the `ensemble_idX`):
[image]

Is there a way to "merge" those coordinates together since they're all the same and only have the coordinate `ensemble` with only one dimension `ensemble_id`?